# MVC5 Server Side Headless Authentication to Azure AD

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, active-directory, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-active-directory

Is there a mechanism in Azure AD to have a completely headless authentication?  Most likely this would mean (in my mind) that the server running the API would have a perpetual authentication session to Azure.

If the purpose matters...  We have a need to expose our thumbnailImage attribute from AD and I just need to make it so that the server doesn't care who requests the image.  So basically we will have `https://domain.com/api/Image/userid` and the api will return an `Image` object (image/jpeg).  I have this functioning internally and now I'm just migrating to Azure.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23256827/mvc-spa-authentication-scenarios-for-azure-ad) question... I just want to confirm two things...

1. [Daemon or Server Application to Web API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn499820.aspx#BKMK_Server) is the method I should be looking at
2. Using this method will function as I'm expecting... a.k.a. WebAPI can access that attribute and use it like I currently use it while inside our internal domain.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed. Azure AD supports the client credential OAuth flow. Yes, you are looking at the right help topic. The corresponding sample application is here: https://github.com/AzureADSamples/Daemon-DotNet.

If you haven't already, use Azure management portal to register your WebAPI as an application in your Azure AD directory and add a client secret (under the section named 'key' in the 'configure' tab of the 'application'). This key will be used as the client credential.

To configure permissions for your WebAPI to be able to call Graph API using client credential flow token, go to the application tab in the Azure Portal, under Azure AD and in the section titled 'Permissions to other applications', add an 'Application Permission' to 'Windows Azure Active Directory' to 'Read directory data'.

What you refer to as perpetual authentication session is basically your WebAPI caching the access token to Graph, and getting a new access token (using client credential flow) when the current access token is about to expire.

Hope this helps.